# Android Firebase how to fetch all child nodes values of a parent node?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database and the structure is as :

```
rides{
     A{
       //related datas for a
     }
     B{
       //related datas for b
     }}
```

so the main problem is i want to get all the values of nodes A and B . I am able to get the values of single node by using the following:

```
   final Firebase ridesDateRef = ref.child("A");

    // Attach an listener to read the data at our posts reference
    ridesDateRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());

            availableRidesList = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println("There are " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " rides");
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                AvailableRidesFirebaseObject rides = postSnapshot.getValue(AvailableRidesFirebaseObject.class);


                AvailableRidesFirebaseObject availableRidesFirebaseObject = new AvailableRidesFirebaseObject();
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setAdded_on(rides.getAdded_on());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setCode(rides.getCode());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setDate_of_ride(rides.getDate_of_ride());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setDropoff_location(rides.getDropoff_location());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setDropoff_coordinate(rides.getDropoff_coordinate());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setFullname(rides.getFullname());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setOffered_by(rides.getOffered_by());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setPickup_location(rides.getPickup_location());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setPickup_coordinate(rides.getPickup_coordinate());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setSeats(rides.getSeats());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setShare(rides.getShare());
                availableRidesFirebaseObject.setVechile_type(rides.getVechile_type());
                availableRidesList.add(availableRidesFirebaseObject);

                System.out.println(rides.getSeats());
            }

            try{
                AvailableRidesListAdapter adapter = new AvailableRidesListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.single_available_ride, availableRidesList);
                availableRideList.setAdapter(adapter);
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }catch(NullPointerException ne){}



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

I am getting single value but I want to get all data value.How can i get that?

Answer (score 6):

Simply start one level higher in the tree and add an extra loop:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot topSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot snapshot: topSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            AvailableRidesFirebaseObject rides = postSnapshot.getValue(AvailableRidesFirebaseObject.class);
            AvailableRidesFirebaseObject availableRidesFirebaseObject = new AvailableRidesFirebaseObject();
            availableRidesFirebaseObject.setAdded_on(rides.getAdded_on());
            availableRidesFirebaseObject.setCode(rides.getCode());
            availableRidesFirebaseObject.setDate_of_ride(rides.getDate_of_ride());
            availableRidesFirebaseObject.setDropoff_location(rides.getDropoff_location());
            availableRidesFirebaseObject.setDropoff_coordinate(rides.getDropoff_coordinate());
            // rest of the code left out for brevity
```

Comment: what if i have 2 nodes and i want to fetch only last two nodes? Let's say if i have A , B and C and i want only values of B and c

Comment: In that case you'd `ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(2)`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: frank , one question , is there anyway to retrieve all the data from a jsonObject without looping inside it ? i have an app that fetchs for 7k users to be displayed into a recyclerview, but the loop takes around 15 - 20 seconds to reach all users and populate the recyclers with all the data. Thanks